# cannot be @Required or @NotNull

Tags: java, android-studio, realm

When using version `4.3.3` of `REALM` for Android development I get the following error:

`Error: Field "groupName" with type "pizware.evaluapp.Models.Group" can not be @Required or @NotNull.`

but I do not use any of those labels for any field. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: paste your code plz

Comment: If you are using kotlin it means you have something like `var groupName: Group` instead of `var groupName: Group?`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use Kotlin, then Realm checks against nullability on your field.

For example,

```
class Blah: RealmObject() {
    var group: Group? = null
}
```

Then `group` doesn't get implicit `@Required` annotation.

But if you do

```
class Blah: RealmObject() {
    var group: Group = Group()
}
```

This won't work, because Realm cannot guarantee non-nullability for a singular link. So it'll throw the error you're getting.

If you want to ignore this because for example you are making a backing field that avoids null value return

```
get() = group ?: Group()
```

Then you can use (since 4.1.0):

```
kapt {
  arguments {
    arg("realm.ignoreKotlinNullability", true)
  }
}
```

In which case Realm won't try to handle your nullability implicitly (and map the Kotlin nullability to the field's `@Required`). But you should use this only if you actually know what you're doing.

Comment: Is there a risk to using the `realm.ignoreKotlinNullability` argument? What does it really mean when it says "Realm cannot guarantee non-nullability for a singular link"?

Comment: It means that Realm single link CAN be null in the database. So if you access the field on a managed RealmObject where it is null, then you will get NPE from Kotlin intrinsics notnull at runtime. The parameter is primarily for allowing non-null backing fields so that you can have a nullable field with some default value (exposed as a not-null property).

Comment: So, in practice, it's not a concern if my single link always has a default value (empty object) instead of null. Right?

Comment: Only if you use a backing field instead of a default value

Comment: Wait..so referring to your example, doing just `var group: Group = Group()` isn't enough to ensure that `var group` is always at least a default empty `Group()`?

Comment: No, you'd need to use `get() = group ?: Group()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168721/discussion-between-aba-and-epicpandaforce).